# Jquery TableSorter SaveSort Reset or Clear

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using table sorter "save sort" widget to save the sorting criteria.

In my case Based on some filter i am loading the table through ajax call. each time i click a button to generate new list my sorting order does not change. which means save sort is working as expected. Note that Here on clicking button i am loading only table part of the page and whole page is not refreshing.

But I want some thing like,

When i reload the entire page (By pressing F5 , or clicking the link )whole page sorting criteria must reset and it should be sorted based on initial sorting criteria. basically save sort must clear or reset.

I have followed [This post](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/123)  and tried

```
 $.tablesorter.storage( $('table')[0], 'tablesorter-savesort', '' );
```

but its giving Error,

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'storage'
```

Jquery Code which does Sorting

```
    $(function() {

     if(0 < $("#trainingList tbody tr").length){ 
         $("#trainingList")
            .tablesorter({widthFixed: true,sortList: [[2,0]],widgets: ["saveSort"],
                headers: { 
                    2: { // <-- zero-based index of column
                        sorter:'ddMMMyy' 
                    } ,
                    3: { // <-- zero-based index of column
                        sorter:'ddMMMyy' 
                    } 
                } 

            })
            .tablesorterPager({container: $(".pager")});

     }       
});
```

Comment: kindly check if you have refrenced the library correctly, because it seems that it is unable to find the storage method

Comment: I think I answered your question in [issue #225](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/225)